# Silent print different shell_exec vs. manual command line

Tags: php, xampp, shell-exec

I would like to automatically print labels locally via a website using silent print. My PHP script running with XAMPP on Windows.

```
<?php
ob_end_clean();
ignore_user_abort();
ob_start();
header("Connection: close");
header("Content-Length: " . ob_get_length());
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://xxx");
ob_end_flush();
flush();

$target = __DIR__ . "\\testToPrintDyn.pdf";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);

$printer = $_POST['printer'];

$commandText = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Foxit Software\\Foxit PDF Reader\\FoxitPDFReader.exe" /t "'.$target.'" "'.$printer.'"';

file_put_contents("print.txt", $commandText);

shell_exec($commandText);
?>
```

Running this script, the label will be printed 90° rotated. When I copy the content of the "print.txt" manually to the command line, everything is printed well. using "exec" ends in the same 90° result.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can proceed here to get closer to the problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Would you consider an alternative ? : rotate the pdf by 90 degree first before sending the print job thru FoxitPDFReader.exe

Comment: @KenLee: Thank you very much for your support. Rotating the PDF from the beginning is only a stopgap solution for me. First I want to try to understand the problem itself - I think that should be the more sustainable solution.

Comment: My further suggestion: try adjusting the width (or height) of the generated pdf and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print from PHP to a label printer, do not use the software supplied. Instead print raw to the port (virtual or otherwise) that the printer uses.

If you printer is USB, set it up as a network enabled printer, set the share name, and that's what you print to.

I recently wrote an offline label print webpage for a company who couldn't print labels when the network went down.

HTH

Comment: Dear Paul, thank you very much for your support. I agree with you - your proposed solution seems to be the better one in the long term. I will think about how I can / should best set something like this up.

Comment: No problem. I have all the development files still, if you'd like a copy. I created a powershell script which does all the lifting, and included a packaged slimmed down version of php in the app installer, so it doesn't have to have php installed on the machine. The installer adds a desktop icon, which when you dbl-click on it, it runs the PS script to load the browser window, and runs the label web page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big step further. I normally start the httpd.exe via Windows Autostart. If I stop the running Apache server and start the same file manually with admin rights, then printing works. If I create httpd.exe as a "task scheduler" with admin rights, then it doesn't work either. But for me this is a much more tangible problem than a rotating PDF page when printing :-D so I'll have to read up a bit more on how to autostart Apache with the right admin rights.